# COALESCE in SQL to Case Statement in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have this sample temp table. I was using the COALESCE in SQL sever. I do not have access right to create tableS in Oracle. Is there a Case statement in Oracle that works as COALESCE in SQL server?

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
    ID INT,
    FIELD1 VARCHAR (5),
    FIELD2 VARCHAR (5),
    FIELD3 VARCHAR (5)
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('555','CVS','E','CIA')

SELECT 
ID,
COALESCE(FIELD1 + '_' + FIELD2 + '_' + FIELD3, FIELD2 + '_' + FIELD1) AS STORE
FROM #TEMP
```

Basically, I want to replace the COALESCE from above my query to Case Statement in Oracle.

edit: I did use this `Field1 ||'_' ||Field2||'_'||Field3 AS Store` in Oracle but the result gives me the extra underscore `_` from Field3 which I don't want to see the underscore.

Comment: Oracle supports coalesce - but it requires **two** parameters not just one (and I believe this is true in SQL Server as well. Passing only one parameter doesn't really make sense). However it uses the SQL standard's operator `||` to concatenate strings. `+` is to add numbers

Comment: I used the concatenate: Field1 ||'_' ||Field2||'_'||Field3 AS Store, but it gives me a extra underscore (_) if Field3 has no value. I don't want to see the (_)

Comment: Did you really want Fields 2 and 1 to be reversed if Field3 is null? Or is that a typo?

Comment: that is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
COALESCE(FIELD1 || '_' || FIELD2 || '_' || FIELD3, FIELD2 || '_' || FIELD1)
```

Will only ever return the first term since even if all 3 fields are `NULL` the expression will evaluate to `__` which is not `NULL`. This is the equivalent of:

```
SELECT TRIM(
         LEADING '_' FROM
         FIELD1
         || NLV2( FIELD2, '_' || FIELD2, NULL )
         || NLV2( FIELD3, '_' || FIELD3, NULL )
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

or

```
SELECT TRIM(
         LEADING '_' FROM
         FIELD1
         || CASE WHEN FIELD2 IS NOT NULL THEN '_' || FIELD2 END
         || CASE WHEN FIELD3 IS NOT NULL THEN '_' || FIELD3 END
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

If you want to reverse Fields 1 & 2 when Field 3 is `NULL` then:

```
SELECT TRIM(
         BOTH '_' FROM
         CASE
         WHEN FIELD3 IS NOT NULL
         THEN FIELD1
              || CASE WHEN FIELD2 IS NOT NULL THEN '_' || FIELD2 END
              || '_' || FIELD3
         ELSE FIELD2 || '_' || FIELD1
         END
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

Comment: @joe `+` is the operator for adding numbers, `||` is the operator for concatenating strings.

Comment: @ MT0, correct. I was mistakenly save this. below was what I re-posted. Thanks.